# List index error when trying to store a specific value using index in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, typeerror

I have a project wherein I have to get the starting and completion time of activities.

For example:

```
activity = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dur = [0, 3, 5, 12, 7]
act_chosen = [2]
t = 2
```

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
# compute starting time and completion time
# 1st: get index of matching values in act_chosen and activity
if isinstance(act_chosen, int):
    act_chosen = [act_chosen]
idx = [y for y, x in enumerate(activity) if x in act_chosen]
print(idx)

# 2nd: get starting time and completion time
starting_time[idx] = t
print(starting_time)

completion_time[idx] = t + dur[idx]
print(completion_time)
```

The objective is to find the `starting_time` and `completion time` of the `act_chosen`. I have `initialized starting time and completion` as a list of 0 values having length of the `activity`.

```
starting_time = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
completion_time = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

At the time when the `activity` is chosen and stored in `act_chosen`, then its `starting_time` should be that time when it is chosen, while its `completion_time` will be `starting_time plus its duration`. With the code above, I am able to get the index `(idx)` of the match between `act_chosen and activity`. But when I try to gets its `starting_time`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

The expected output for the example above is:

```
starting_time = [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
completion_time = [0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

Any help/suggestion to get rid of the error would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar is there a way where I can call the index of the match between activity and act_chosen aside from the code above? Because I have to use this index to properly get the correct order in starting_time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a list as a list index. You need to iterate over `idx` to update each of the corresponding elements.

```
for i in idx:
    start_time[i] = t
    completion_time[i] = t + dur[i]
```

You probably don't even need the `idx` list, just do it in the loop over `activity`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(activity):
    if x in act_chosen:
        start_time[i] = t
        completion_time[i] = t + dur[i]
```

Or maybe you should use `numpy`, which allows operating on arrays like that.

Comment: You can with `numpy`, may be this is where the confusion comes from

Comment: I kinda understand it now. Really big help! Thank you so much!

Comment: @6502 what do you mean?

Comment: @AJGayeta The `numpy` package allows you to operate on arrays all at once without having to write loops. You can use a list of indexes as you tried.

Comment: @Barmar does this mean, if I have to use the code that I have so far, starting_time must be a numpy? do I understand it, right?

Comment: Yes, you would use numpy arrays instead of lists.